# Trouble with JSON Parsing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I am trying to remove all the empty/null/spaces/undefined spaces in this JSON, but I am stuck. This is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        JSON Example
    </title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

</style>

<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var data = {
  "first_name": "Sick",
  "last_name": "Nick",
  "email": "sick,nicke@address.com",
  "gender": null,
  "invitations": [
    {
      "from": "",
      "code": null
    }
  ],
  "company": {
    "name": "",
    "industries": []
  },
  "address": {
    "city": "Minnesota",
    "state": "MN",
    "zip": "14221",
    "street": " "
  }
};



//eliminate all the null values from the data
function clean(obj) {
  var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
  console.log("The clone is: "+clone);
  for (var propName in obj) { 
    var toRemove = obj[propName];
    if (toRemove === null || toRemove === [] || toRemove === {} || toRemove === "" || toRemove === " ") {
      obj.splice(obj.indexOf(propName),1);
    }
  }
    return obj;
}

clean(data);


</script>
  <p>"The value is: "<span id="data"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have a preliminary function written for it, but I don't quite grasp the idea fully. Can anyone help me by pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` will not remove null, empty arrays or zero length strings ... you'll need to look at the extra arguments you can supply to those functions to do what you want

Comment: There may be way better ways to do this, but [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypcbwq5a/) seems to do what you want - note, added extra levels of data - the while loop can handle probably 500 levels deep - I think the loop needs to run twice for each level of data - as I said, probably much better way to do this

Comment: One thing I would like to add here is, you cannot call `splice` and `indexOf` functions on an object. They are defined on array.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do so much cleanup, why even bother with `JSON.parse(JSON.sringify(data))` in the first place? Ain't the purpose of this construct to have a quick and easy way to make a deep clone without the need to iterate over the objects yourself? But you have to, to clean up your clone.

check this out:

```js
var data = {
  "first_name": "Sick",
  "last_name": "Nick",
  "email": "sick,nicke@address.com",
  "gender": null,
  "invitations": [{
    "from": "",
    "code": null
  }],
  "company": {
    "name": "",
    "industries": []
  },
  "address": {
    "city": "Minnesota",
    "state": "MN",
    "zip": "14221",
    "street": " "
  }
};

function clone(value) {
  if (typeof value === "object") {
    let _clone;
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      for(let v of value){
        let w = clone(v);
        if(w !== undefined){
          _clone || (_clone = []);
          _clone.push(w);
        }
      }
    } else if (value !== null) {
      for (let key of Object.keys(value)) {
        let w = clone(value[key]);
        if (w !== undefined) {
          _clone || (_clone = {});
          _clone[key] = w;
        }
      }
    }
    
    return _clone;
  }
  
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    return value.trim() ? 
      value : 
      undefined;
  }

  return value;
}

console.log(clone(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second parameter of JSON.stringify for apply the clean up for the object or simply clean up your object with a function like this

```
function isArray(arr){
return Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === '[object Array]';
}

function isObject(obj){
return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]';
}

function clean(obj){
if(typeof obj === 'string' || typeof obj === 'number'){
return obj;
}

if (isArray(obj)){
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
var value = obj[i];
if (value){
if (isArray(value) && value.length > 0){
arr.push(clean(value))
}

if(!isArray(value)){
arr.push(value)
}
}
}
return arr;
}

var object = {};
for(var key in obj){
var val = obj[key];
if((isArray(val) && val.length > 0) || isObject(val)){
object[key] = clean(val);
}

if((typeof val === 'string' && val) || typeof val === 'number'){
object[key] = clean(val)
}
}

return object;
}

var obj = {
name: '',
arr:[],
name2: 'yode',
age: 27,
nested: {
name: 'myname'
}
}

var d = clean(obj);

alert(JSON.stringify(d))
```

I hope It can help you